# Receiving, sending and saving files through Bluetooth Classic with an ESP32

Tags: bluetooth, esp32, arduino-esp32

I am working on a project right now that can work way better if I am able to receive and save files from an Android app to the flash memory of an ESP32CAM and send said files back.

I have looked around but haven't really found anything on the matter. The Android app sends tthe messages through the Java intents and activities.

Does anyone have any idea how I can receive the file and save it to either flash memory or an SD card?

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @romkey yes, I have edited my post, sorry for forgetting to add that.